# Android Widget:-P roblem Loading Widget (error in xml file)

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, widget

i m newbie. i m trying to make a android widget and when i run it, the widget give me problem loading problem and there are nothing error in the logcat... i tried remove all the buttons and edit text and it able to show the widget. and i m here to ask helps to check which mistake in the xml files that leads to problem loading widget. thankz in advance..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >

        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Ans"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button19"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button21"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If it fails on compile then please post the compiler error in your question. If it throws exception on render please post the exception detail in your question. That can help people better identify the problem you have. Not many ppl run compiler in their brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no major problem in this layout, may be it will be in back-end code. I executed this code... here is the screenshot attached with my button style.In preview some time it shows java.lang.coopy error,but try to deploy in a device and see. [image]

Answer (score 0):

As far i see, there are multiple LinearLayouts with unset orientations. Thats no real problem so far but you should propably switch to a simpler layouting with relativelayouts or something like this.
Also Android Developer Portal states that EditTexts aren't supported for widgets. This might be difficult since EditText inherit from TextView.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout